# Apply formula to large range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large range (upto 60k lines) which I would like to apply a formula too.

A loop would take too long.  The formula would apply to info on the row so wouldn't be the same exactly but the row would be the only variable.

What's the best way to do this?  I thought I would use VBA rather than Excel to make sure the spreadsheet didn't get too cumbersome.

Comment: `formula would apply to info on the row so wouldn't be the same exactly` -- that means the formula is the same, exactly. Please give examples of formulas for row 1 and row 2.

Comment: If you do this in VBA I'd recommend simply using VBA to evaluate the formula, and write only the results to the worksheet.  Unless you *need* to maintain the formula in the cell, it will run much faster and be less prone to "breaking" if you do it this way.

Comment: I just thought if I got vba to paste the answer then it would save on formulas on excel.  Seeing as the sheet has 50000 lines I thought that might be a good idea. This is the formula I wish to have the values for =SUMIFS($J$2:$J$50000,$C$2:$C$50000,C2,$E$2:$E$50000,E2,$F$2:$F$50000,F2,$A$2:$A$50000,K2)

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple way to do what you want. If the formula takes too long to update it may be better to calc the result using VBA and output the result to the range.

Assume you want the formula `=INDEX($M:$M,MATCH(A2,$N:$N,0),0)` in rows D2:D60000

i. Turn on the macro recorder

ii. Enable Use Relative References

[image]

iii. Enter the formula required in a single cell (ensure if dragged down it will be correct for all rows)

iv. Turn off the macro recorder

v. In the VB Editor find the formula recorded - eg

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(C13,MATCH(RC[-5],C14,0),0)"
```

vi. Apply the formula to the required range using

```
Sheet1.range("D2:D60000").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(C13,MATCH(RC[-5],C14,0),0)"
```

Comment: Ah I forgot about relative references I used to use it all the time when I used to record macros and not try and write them! Actually it is a sum if so may need to be a bit cleverer with the formulas but could have a play with it once it has been recorded. Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE - I have managed to get the formula into the cell just not clear how to get the value only. I thought if I used rngcopy.value="=IF(RC[-10]="""","""",IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])=2,RC[-10]-3,IF(WEEKDAY(RC[-10])<>2,RC[-10]-1)))" would work but it gives the formula and not the value.

Comment: you can use the cell.Text property to get the cell text.